Why does my <audio> not autoplay when I refresh the page?
I have 2 audio tags, with the first one working fine (the audio tag associated with the button) and the second tag simply not working whenever I refresh the page or just not work at all. Is there anything I can do to solve this?
<audio hidden loop autoplay>
            <source src= "music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
          </audio>

(note: If I'm doing something wrong whether it's submitting a question or for example not putting any comments in the code, I
m very sorry. I'm a beginner and it's one of my first coding projects)
I tried to remove different attributes from the tag which I think did work but I need to loop the audio one way or another so is there a possible workaround if I can't fix my issue?

Please include a text-base [mcve] in the question, rather than just a link to a github repo/website

Got it @KIKOSoftware, I'm working on changing the body of my question to make it easier for people to understand my issue.

Afaik, autoplay is disabled by most browsers in many scenarios. The audio must be triggered by a user interaction, or the volume must be off.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability

@Carcigenicate The audio in this situation is supposed to be background music for my site. Is there a work around to make it autoplay?

Sadly autoplay had been disabled by Chrome not too long ago :(. Luckily there's a way to play the music but it can only happen when the user "interacts" with the website.
Solution
<body>
<div>
    <audio id="player" hidden loop><source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>

<script>function musicPlay() {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
}</script>
</div>
</body>

By doing this, the audio will play as soon as the user presses a button or interacts with a slider etc.

Could document.getElementById('player').play() not be run on document.onload?
